# Rotate around specific axis according to different object

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm essentially trying to animate an industrial cart going forwards, backwards, and spinning on center, all with swivel casters moving accordingly. I need to have all 4 casters spinning on their own specified axes, then connect those joints to the cart so they can spin according to the direction the cart is moving. Still pretty new to Blender so not sure if something like this is even possible, any help would be appreciated.

[image: Full cart with casters (No wheels shown)]

[image: Underneath casters showing the axis it should rotate on]

Comment: In Blender for the most part you can't access a previous frame. Frames are calculated independently. So in order to get the direction of the object, you need to for example duplicate the object and offset its animation by 1 frame. Now you can use a driver that takes the difference of positions of the two objects, and that's the direction. However, if you want the wheels to smoothly change orientation, this alone won't be enough…